Docker bind mount or volume
I am trying to use docker compose to share a directory between my container and my host.
I understand that I cant use a normal bind mount, as bind mounts copy the directory from the host into the container, overwriting what is there. I would like the files inside the container to take priority.
My docker compose file looks like this:
services:
  environment:
    image: dev-image:latest
    container_name: dev
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - my-volume:/root

volumes:
  my-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /path/to/my/mountpoint/directory

This mounts the files, however, I cannot control the mount point on the host. It is always going to .local/....... How can I change this so that it is mounted in a local directory? Everything I see says use bind mounts, but I dont think I can do for the reason above.

Why exactly do you need access to the files on the host?  What goes wrong if the host content takes precedence?  (If the container content should take precedence, what do you expect will happen if a file changes in the image, why, and how would you keep track of it?)  My first recommendation would be to delete this volume entirely, and use something like an HTTP PUT/GET API to interact with the logical objects in your server.

I want to edit code in my local environment, but build and run it in the container where all the dependencies are built.

So the image I have contains a built version of several large projects. I do not want to have to rebuild them on my own machine. I just want to edit a few files, do a git push, and then rebuild inside the container where I can benefit from the CMake cache etc

If it's a well-built compiled C/C++ image, the image probably doesn't contain the build tools or the source code.  I generally recommend using a local development environment even if you're eventually using Docker for deployment, so that you're not hiding away the tools in a container where you can't access them, and so that things like CMake caches do work consistently and don't get lost on image rebuilds.
